# Stretchable images @2x issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have both a "normal" sized image and an @2x image. It's a stretchable image and works fine on normal resolution, but on the retina display it doesn't work at all. The image is cut off and just looks odd. I've made sure the left cap width and top cap height of the @2x image is double that of the normal image (which is what I'm setting in code), but it doesn't work.

Can anyone run through how to create and set up a stretchable @2x image for retina displays?

Comment: How are you using your images in your code?

Comment: yes - please add the code that references the images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried keeping the cap width the same? It’s probably in points, not pixels.

Comment: I wasn't changing the cap width - it was set as the cap width for the normal version. I've fixed the issue though - it had to do with mirroring the image in code before stretching it. I'm still not sure why it didn't work with the @2x image, but I've just mirrored the actual image now instead and it's working fine. Thanks for the help.